# php psr-0 restful webservice library

Tags: php, psr-0

is anyone aware of lightweight restful lib that is namespaced following psr-0 guide lines.

looking at slim, epiphany but would like something that is better structured and namespaced as per psr-0 recommendations.

slim claims to be psr-0 compliant but its not really and 'achieves' this by using is own autoloader.

any tips greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/) is very similar to Slim but with much better architecture IMO and it is psr-0 compliant.

Comment: cheers @prodigitalson - I'm also looking at tonic.

Comment: Hadnt heard of [Tonic](http://peej.github.com/tonic/)... looks nice. I like the fact that annotations are used to map routing.